# how to parse collection in XML structure with serde

Tags: xml, rust

I need to parse XML file containing a collection of structures.
I am currently using `serde_xml_rs` but it does not seem to support this case:

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;

const DATA_XML: &str = r###"<data>
    <name>test</name>
    <list>
        <item>
            <something>1</something>
        </item>
        <item>
            <something>2</something>
        </item>
        <item>
            <something>3</something>
        </item>
    </list>
</data>
"###;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename = "data")]
struct Data {
    name: String,
    list: Vec<Item>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Item {
    something: String,
}

fn main() {
    let data: Data = serde_xml_rs::from_str(DATA_XML).unwrap();
    println!("data = {:#?}", data);

}
```

Above code fails with

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Custom { field: "missing field `something`" }', examples/xml-list.rs:32:55
```

Is there a way to explicitly indicate name of the container (or item) element?
I suppose that might be the missing piece here.

Comment: It seems work on `serde-xml-rs` has seized over a year ago. I recommend you look for another crate.

Comment: @cafce25 Indeed. I'd recommend `quick_xml`.

Comment: thanks - I did both, ie. switched to  `quick_xml` and added the extra layer for collection (seems to be still necessary)

Comment: Yes. Your issue is independent of the serializer used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the list in an object:

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;

const DATA_XML: &str = r###"<data>
    <name>test</name>
    <list>
        <item>
            <something>1</something>
        </item>
        <item>
            <something>2</something>
        </item>
        <item>
            <something>3</something>
        </item>
    </list>
</data>
"###;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename = "data")]
struct Data {
    name: String,
    list: List,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename = "list")]
struct List {
    item: Vec<Item>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename = "item")]
struct Item {
    something: String,
}

fn main() {
    let data: Data = serde_xml_rs::from_str(DATA_XML).unwrap();
    println!("data = {:#?}", data);
}
```